# Ext Js : add nested panels dynamically

Tags: nested, panel, addition, dynamic

I have several records of the same type that I want to show on the screen. I thought about creating several panels that will print the data of each record. I chose this solution because data structure is too complex to be printed in a simple grid. Here is a simplified example of that structure :

```
{
    label: 'myLabel',
    {
        attr1: 'value1',
        attr2: 'value2'
    }
    startValidityDate: oneDay,
    endValidityDate: anotherDay
}
```

I try to add dynamically nested panels in my current panel :

```
var myStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    id: 'myStore',
    restful: true,
    idProperty: 'OID',
    root: 'tbas',
    proxy: myProxy,
    reader: myReader,
    autoLoad: false, 
    listeners: {
        'load': function(data){
        var records = data.getRange();
        var currStore = null;
        for(var i=0; i<records.length; i++) {
            currStore = new Ext.Panel({
            layout:'vBox',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: I18nManager.get('label_ttbaUI_label'),
                name: 'tbaLabel',
                value: records[i].data.tbaLabel
                },{
                xtype: 'textfield',
                fieldLabel: I18nManager.get('label_ttbaUI_label'),
                name: 'tbaOid',
                value: records[i].data.tbaoid
                }] 
            });
        recordList.add(currStore);
console.log("------------------------------");
console.log(currStore);
        }
        recordList.doLayout();
        }
    }
});

var recordList = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'recordList',
    renderTo: 'recordPart',
    layout:'vBox',
    title: I18nManager.get('label_ttbaUI_selected_tariffs')
});
recordList.doLayout();
```

In the firebug console, the UI objects seems to be ok.

My problem is that the recordList elements are not visible

I can see that they exist in the FB console, but they are not well printed on the screen.

Did I forgot something that make the elements hidden ? or bad printed ?
I'm sure that it is a CSS problem, some trouble with ext-all.css : when I remove the content of that CSS, I can see my fields

There must be something wrong in the way I wrote the code so that it causes the render problem WDYT ???